# Tag list protected mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here is a part of my mathematica script, which gives me an error when I try to run it. The error is something like "Tag list in ... is protected". Looking at the attached code, can anyone immidiatly see what's wrong? I know you obviously can't see the whole code, but I am pretty sure the error must be in the syntax of the attached part.

```
Subscript[j, crit] := \[CapitalDelta]t;
t = {};
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - GaAs] = {}; 
 \[Theta] = {};
 Subscript[d, NW] = {};
 Subscript[x, \As] = {};
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - As] = {};
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l] = {};
 Subscript[L, NW] = {};\[CapitalDelta]t := 10;
 Subscript[n, steps] := 2;
 For[i = 1, i < Subscript[n, steps], i++,
    t = Append[t, i*\[CapitalDelta]t];(*Growth time*)
    Subscript[x, As] = Append[Subscript[x, As], 
         If[i == 1, 
            Subscript[x, As - start], 
            Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - As][[i - 1]]/Subscript[\[CapitalNu],
                 l][[i - 1]]
                      ] ];(*As mole fraction in liquid phase*)
    Subscript[d, NW] = Append[Subscript[d, NW], 
    If[i == 1, Subscript[d, start], 
        dNW[Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]], 
        Subscript[\[Theta], GaAs][Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]], 
        Subscript[d, NW][[i - 1]], T]]]];(*Diameter of the growth interface*)
    \[Theta] = Append[\[Theta], 
      If[i == 1, Subscript[\[Theta], start], 
    \[Theta][Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]], 
            Subscript[d, NW][[i]], T]]];
Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l] = Append[Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l], 
       If[i == 1, Subscript[\[CapitalNu], lstart], 
Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]] + 
   (Subscript[I, vl - As - GaAs][fAs, If[i == 1, Subscript[x, As - start], 
 Subscript[x, As][[i - 1]]], 
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]], 
 Subscript[\[Theta], l][[i]], T] + 
 Subscript[I, vl - Ga - GaAs][fGa, 
   If[i == 1, Subscript[x, As - start], 
 Subscript[x, As][[i - 1]]], 
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]], 
 Subscript[\[Theta], l][[i]], T])*\[CapitalDelta]t -Subscript[\[CapitalDelta]N, ML]]];
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - As] = Append[Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - As], 
   If[i == 1, Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - As - start], 
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l - As][[i - 1]] + 
 Subscript[I, vl - As - GaAs][fAs, 
 If[i == 1, Subscript[x, As - start], Subscript[x, As][[i]]], 
 Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i]], Subscript[\[Theta], l][[i]], T]*
   \[CapitalDelta]t -    Subscript[\[CapitalDelta]N, ML]]]] ;(*Number of As atoms in liquid*)
ListPlot[\[Theta]]
```

Comment: actually upload the pic to the site. I'm for sure not clicking on a  random html link. Also If you posed the actual full error instead of 'something like' that would help a lot.

Comment: "Tag list in ... is protected" almost always means you have an = (which means assign this value to this name) when you needed to have == (which means compare the stuff to the left with the stuff to the right and tell whether they are the same or not). Edit down your example to the smallest possible bit of code with the smallest amount of data that still shows the thing you are trying to do and still shows that error message and paste it into your post with 4 spaces in front of each line of the data and code. That preserves the code and someone can scrape and execute it to find your error.

Comment: I have removed image and added code. I tried to add image to the site, but I don't have enough reputation points apparantly. I hope you can make sense of the code even though it is very messy. The error is: SetDelayed::write: "Tag List in {}[Nl_,dNW_,T_] is Protected."

Comment: First, the bad news. You have "drunk the desktop publishing Koolaid" and are trying to make Mathematica input look like published notation. Subscripts are not "real variables", they are a patch stuck on by Wolfram and they don't act like real variables. When complicated code full of Subscripts work I am astonished. Usually the first thing I do is delete all Subscript and see if the code works. Next. you are using Theta as a name for a list and also as a function Theta[Subscript[N,1][[i-1]],Subscript[d,NW][[i]],T] unless that is a typo. Theta is either a variable or a function, not both.

Comment: first use of Subscripts should usually be avoided. Focus on making code work not on making it look pretty. Second, break your code into multiple cells so that you can see exactly which line causes the error (hence show only relevant stuff here)

Comment: one other thing I see a capital `I` in there which undoubtedly should be `i`. ( `I` is the imaginary unit in Mathematica)

Comment: Either it is a typo or a scrape-n-paste error because you use Subscript[d,NW] and also dNW[Subscript[n,1][[i-1]]. Likewise you have Subscript[I,vl-As-GaAs][fAs...]. Anything[something] is saying Anything is a function and something is the argument. You have these a number of places in your included code. Can you check to see if all these are what you really mean, fix any typos, re-paste the corrected code and add a note when you are done with that?

Comment: And he is using N, when that is defined as a function name by Mathematica, either I or N may or may not work inside Subscript.

Comment: Well thats fun, `Subscript[I,x]` can indeed be used as a symbol. It looks near identical to `Subscript[i,x]` on the screen..nice if you wanted to deliberately obfuscate your code.

Comment: Okay so I should basically try to rewrite everything without subscripts. Is there any simple way to do that for a large code? This code is much large because it contains lines and lines of definitions of constants and different functions.

Comment: Before you start trying to redo everything answer or fix these.  Subscript[x, \As] = {}; (* is this a paste error? *)
dNW[Subscript[\[CapitalNu],l] ...] (* is this a paste error or is that really a function*)
Subscript[\[Theta], GaAs][Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]] ...](*same question*)
\[Theta][Subscript[\[CapitalNu], l][[i - 1]] ...](*same question*)
Subscript[I, vl - Ga - GaAs][fGa ...](*same question*)
Subscript[I, vl - As - GaAs][fAs ...](*same question*)